# vscode+vetur: go to definition from .js files doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, visual-studio-code, vetur

I have Vetur installed and a `jsconfig.js` file in the root of my project. It is a javascript vue-cli 3 project.

I **do can** go to definition from a .vue file to another .vue file.

I **do can** go to definition from a .js file to another .js file.

I **do can** go to definition from a .vue file to a .js file.

But,

I **cannot** go to definition from a .js file to a .vue file. When I try to do so, vscode opens the 'go to references' widget.

Contents of my `jsconfig.file`:

```js
{
  // This file is required for VSCode to understand webpack aliases
  "module": "es6",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

    "baseUrl": ".",
    // Relative to "baseUrl"
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "mocks/*": ["./tests/unit/specs/__mocks__/*"],
      "test-e2e/*": ["./tests/e2e/specs/*"],
      "test-unit/*": ["./tests/unit/specs/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    ".git",
    ".app-cache",
    ".npm",
    ".npm-tmp",
    "dist",
    "dist*",
    "node_modules",
    "subfolder/dist",
    "subfolder/node_modules",
    "**/dist/*",
    "**/node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```

I know there are **a lot** of issues related to this on GitHub, but all of them seem to be related to typescript projects or only referring to `.vue` files. I could not find any solution to this specific problem.

I tried to install the 'vue peek' extension, but nothing changed.

Comment: did you ever manage to make this work? I have a lot of Mixins I use in vue defined as .js files. SublimeText handles the Goto definition perfectly, but VSCode doesn't. It's so frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but more information about the problem since I also have it and I don't know how to solve it.

The problem seems to be that `*.vue` files are handled by Vetur extension. Vetur extension is invoking typescript on the `<script>` in a way that allows it to correctly resolve `*.vue` file imports.

However, `*.js` files are handled by typescript directly and typescript have no idea what `*.vue` is and it is trying to resolve it as if it were a filename without an extension by appending various default extensions: `*.vue.ts`, `*.vue.tsx`, `*.vue.js`, etc. That's why it is not finding it.

I ran `npx typescript --traceResolution` on the code and in the output is the following:

```
======== Resolving module './App.vue' from 'src/main.js'. ========
Module resolution kind is not specified, using 'NodeJs'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location 'src/App.vue', target file type 'TypeScript'.
File 'src/App.vue.ts' does not exist.
File 'src/App.vue.tsx' does not exist.
File 'src/App.vue.d.ts' does not exist.
Directory 'src/App.vue' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location 'src/App.vue', target file type 'JavaScript'.
File 'src/App.vue.js' does not exist.
File 'src/App.vue.jsx' does not exist.
Directory 'src/App.vue' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
======== Module name './App.vue' was not resolved. ========
```